# String based on little endian to uint16 (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, hex, byte, endianness

I hope I'm explaining this clearing.

I've received data from third party in binary format.

When I read certain bytes in the string I get the following values

&H80 &H00

According to the developer that's sending the info its little endian first so in fact that shoudl be

&H00 &H80 which gives the value of 128 which is what I'm told is the correct value.

Now reserving the string isn't an issue but how do I get the value of 128?

I've been looking at BITCONVERT and SYSTEM.TEXT.ENCODING, I think I might be on the right path but I'm just missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must stop using a string first, it is not capable of storing binary data and will arbitrarily corrupt the data when the string is normalized or crash your program when it encounters an invalid surrogate pair.  You must use a MemoryStream or Byte() array instead.  Now BitConverter or BinaryReader are simple to get going.

Answer (score 0):

If you already read the bytes into an array, you can use the `BitConverter` class, e.g.:

```
Dim input As Byte() = {&H80, &H00}
Dim result As Int16 = BitConverter.ToInt16(input, 0) ' is now 128 '
```

Comment: Dominic - that's my problem, when I read the string into bytes() I get either bytes {127, 32, 0, 0) or bytes {0, 0, 32 127}.  What should I use to read the string into bytes UTF8.GetBytes, Unicode.GetBytes etc.?

Comment: How excatly does your string look like? Why is it a string in the first place instead of a `byte()`?

Comment: @JimBuckleyBarrett - You keep saying string, are you really using a string?

Comment: Yes the data is read in to a string.  Its very old code but at the time the data was in ascii format originally.

Comment: I should point out that I do read the string into a bytes() and that shows me {127, 32, 0, 0) with little endian first - should be {0, 0, 32 127} of course.  The question is how to reverse the bytes and get 128 value from it.

Comment: If you just want to reverse the byte array, just call Array.Reverse or the Reverse() extension method.